# English translation of Parisian Alfonsine tables (the 1400s)

Tags: astronomy, translations

I'm interested in an English translation of the Alfonsine tables published in Paris in the 1400s. I know there is an English translation of what survived of earlier Alfonsine tables from Castile, but that's not what I'm interested in. If you know of software that implements the algorithms implied by the table, that would be good too.

Link to the book review of what I'm *not* interested is [this](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2004JHA....35..479S).

Link to the Latin version of what I want is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=4ppKAAAAcAAJ).